# What does "user removed" -25 mean?

Tags: support, reputation

I just noticed on Feb 28 on my Travel account it says -25 user removed....what is this?  Why does it say this? I don't remember doing anything wrong. Is it a bug because obviously I was not removed?  Hope this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug -- it means that a user account was deleted, together with all their votes. The user in question has apparently voted 25 points worth of posts you wrote.